# Consolidate SQL Union With JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Let's say I have 2 tables (`bar_helper` and `bar`). I have a query that retrieves records based on a `JOIN` between the tables and some condition.

Essentially, my first result set is joined and I want my second one to be unconditional and just based on one table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.barId, b.foo 
FROM bar_helper a 
    JOIN bar b ON a.barId=b.id
WHERE a.color='blue' AND b.type='wood';
```

This works fine. However, now I need to also get a second set of `bar` records (unconditional of `bar_helper`). I don't want to execute a second query and then merge results. It looks like I can solve this with `UNION` (not using `All` bc deduped is fine)

So now my query would be something like.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.barId, b.foo 
FROM bar_helper a 
    JOIN bar b ON a.barId=b.id
WHERE a.color='blue' AND b.type='wood'

UNION

SELECT id, foo
FROM bar where magnitude=10;
```

This seems to work and I get 1 resultset that combines both. Is there a more consolidated way to do this though? Can I just use `OR`. The `JOIN` is what's confusing me. I'm looking for something that's like..
"get these first set of results"....."but...also...get these too".

Any insights?

Comment: Have you tried NEED PARENS  WHERE (a.color='blue' AND b.type='wood') OR (magnitude=10) ?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's part of `SELECT DISTINCT` - and works in the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT a.barId, b.foo ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: @Brad, makes no difference - since AND has higher precedence than OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.id, b.foo
FROM bar b 
WHERE b.magnitude = 10
   OR 
   (b.type = 'wood' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bar_helper a WHERE a.color = 'blue' AND a.barId = b.id))
```

Comment: Perfect! Consolidated and makes sense. Do you know of the performance difference between your way and the `UNION` and `JOIN` I had above?

Comment: @user2402616 Usually EXISTS performs better than joins because it does not need to scan the whole table but it returns as soon as it finds the 1st matching condition. In any case you must test it with your actual data.

Comment: Makes sense about short-circuiting upon finding a match and not having to do full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

If you reorganize the logic a little this is just a LEFT JOIN:

```sql
SELECT b.id, b.foo
FROM bar b
LEFT JOIN bar_helper a ON b.id = a.barid
WHERE
    b.Magnitude = 10
OR (b.type = 'wood' AND a.color = 'blue')
```

Comment: This made my problem more easier to understand. I love both answers. Good to learn about EXISTS and how it could be more performant than JOIN.